# How can I use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in an Azure Function?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-active-directory

I created an Azure function via the portal and want to open a connection to a Sql Server using an Active Directory Managed Identity.  In order for this connection string to work, I have to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.  But when I try to use this library inside of Azure, the function stops working.

It is as simple as adding:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
```

to the top of a newly created Azure function inside the portal.  I can't use the standard System.Data.SqlClient namespace as when I do a new connection string, it doesn't like the connection string of

```
Server=db.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;Encrypt=True;Database=myDb
```

How can I open a Sql Connection using the Active Directory Managed Identity authentication method inside an Azure function?

Comment: I believe you have to use [`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/5.1.0-preview2.22314.2).

Comment: @GauravMantri Correct.  But adding that using statement to the top of the Azure function or just doing a #r Microsoft.Data.SqlClient will break the function.

Comment: Ah...I was not aware of that. I used it only in a web API and not in an Azure Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add package references in function.proj file and upload it into function app then packages will be added to code.
Below are steps I followed to connect sql database and retrieving data from a table.

1. Have created sql data base with one table.
2. Next created a function app with run time stack .Net and version    3.1.
3. Added Sql data base connection string to function app configuration as shown below.
   [image]
4. Created a Http trigger function and replaced default code with following code,

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

#r "System.Configuration"

using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Net;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

using System.Configuration;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

public  static  async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)

{

string responseMessage;

//We retrieve the id field, which comes as a parameter to the function, by deserializing req.Content.

string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

//If there is no username, we return the error message.

var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnection", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

//Azure SQLDB Log

var logAdded = true;

try

{

//We get the Connection String in the Function App Settings section we defined.

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

{

//Opens Azure SQL DB connection.

connection.Open();

string qs = $"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Persons] where [Personid] = 1";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qs, connection);

string queryop = "";

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())

{

queryop = sqlDatoToJson(reader);

}

responseMessage = (queryop);

connection.Close();

}

}

catch(Exception e)

{

logAdded = false;

log.LogError(e.ToString());

responseMessage = e.ToString();

// connection.Close();

}

return  new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);

}

static String sqlDatoToJson(SqlDataReader dataReader)

// transform the returned data to JSON

{

var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Load(dataReader);

string JSONString = string.Empty;

JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);

return JSONString;

}
```

5. Added below code in a file with name function.proj and uploaded to function using upload option.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.78" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" Version="3.2.3" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]
6. Once file uploaded, you can see file in dropdown.
[image]
7. Tested function and able to get data from data base,
[image]
Reference [link](https://anupamchand.medium.com/azure-functions-reading-sql-database-77f6ec17cc1b)